# MySQL 5.7 unable to create desc index

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Version: 5.7.17 on Windows 10

I used the following SQL statement to generate a table.

```
CREATE TABLE `attributes` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `name_idx` (`name` DESC)
)
```

I tried that statement from Java Code. I tried this statement also from MySQL Workbench.
It never creates a descending index on name.
Is this a known issue?
Have I made a mistake?

Comment: Uuh, just now I found this http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-descending-indexes-in-mysql/ MySQL 5.7 does not support DESC indexes, so why am I able to select DESC as an option for an index in MySQL Workbench...

Comment: There are a few things that originally had no support, but were accepted by the SQL parser (CHECK is another example). Things imporve over time.